# How can I install Email::Sender on windows?

Tags: windows, perl, email, smtp

I'm working with Perl on Windows. I will try to send mail with [Email::Sender](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender) module. But I couldn't install module for [Email::Sender](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender).

Comment: What error did you get? Which Perl distribution are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the CPAN module `Email::Sender` (Perl is case sensitive), and not some other module that isn't in CPAN, then you use the package installer that came with your Perl distribution.

In most cases that will be:

```
cpan Email::Sender
```

There are [more details and methods](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) linked from the Getting Started section of the [CPAN homepage](http://www.cpan.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I used `cpan Email::Sender` command, and then output is like followings :

```
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /home/user name/.cpan/Metadata
Database was generated on Wed, 04 Apr 2012 09:59:04 GMT
Running install for module Email::Sender
Running make for R/RJ/RJBS/Email-Sender-0.110005.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::MD5 loaded ok
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok
Checksum for /home/user name/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Email-Sender
-0.110005.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/user name/.cpan/build for sizes
sh: /home/user: No such file or directory
/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Uncompressed /home/user name/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Email-Sender
-0.110005.tar.gz successfully
Using Tar:/bin/tar xvf /home/user name/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Em
ail-Sender-0.110005.tar:
/bin/tar: /home/user: Cannot open: No such file or directory
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Couldn't untar /home/user name/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Email-Send
er-0.110005.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

use the command given below:

```
cpan Email::Sender
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `Email::Sender` has nice and simple command structure, it's not part of the standard Perl installation. However, [Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) is.

Yes, `Net::SMTP` is a bit more complex to use, but you probably already have it installed, and if your Perl scripts are used on various machines -- including machines where installing CPAN modules might not be possible -- it's one less complication that you have to deal with.

If you really prefer `Email::Sender`, you can install it depending on what type of Perl installation do you have. If you have ActiveState, you can use the Perl Package Manager (it's in the Start Menu under ActiveState) to download `Email::Sender` for you.

Looking at your error messages, try first installing `Archive::Tar` and `Compress::Zlib` and see if that helps installing `Email::Sender`.

If not, and you have [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) installed, go to the `/home/user name/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS` directory, and manually uncompress the file `Em
ail-Sender-0.110005.tar` using 7Zip. If that fails, go to the CPAN page for [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Sender/lib/Email/Sender.pm) manually download the gripped tar ball, and uncompress it using 7Zip.

Once that's done, you'll have to manually run the following commands:

```
 C> perl Makefile.PL
```

`C> nmake`<sup>1</sup>

```
 C> nmake test
 C> nmake install
```

After all, that's what CPAN does.

One more thing: Take a look at my [svn-watch.pl](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Watcher-Hook/blob/master/svn-watch.pl) program. Around line #767 is an actual example of using `Net::SMTP`. I also use `Mail::Sendmail` which is another Perl email module because some sites have trouble with `Net::SMTP`, so I give them the option to use `Mail::Sendmail` instead. You can see the logic I use to determine whether `Mail::Sendmail` is installed, and if it is, to use that. If `Mail::Sendmail` isn't installed, I default to `Net::SMTP`. That test logic is on line #739 to #742.

Hope this helps.

---

<sup>1.</sup>The command may be either `nmake` or `make` depending on your Perl distro.